# splitting a string by &nbsp;.....javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap selectpicker and i need a delimiter to split out the text selected. The reason for this question is when a user selects multiple options in the bootstrap select, the text in not separated by a delimiter like the values:

```
   <select class="selectpicker" multiple>
       <option value=1>Mustard</option>
       <option value=2>Ketchup</option>
      <option value=3>Relish</option>
       </select>
```

The javascript to create the picker:

```
   $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

The user selects mustard and ketchup. To get the values:

```
   $('.selectpicker').val();//outputs '1,2'
```

Notice the comma delimiter. But i need the text as well:

```
  $('.selectpicker option:selected').text(); //outputs 'MustardKetchup
```

Notice no delimiter. So i added an invisible delimiter like so:

```
    <option value=1>Mustard&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
       <option value=2>Ketchup&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
      <option value=3>Relish&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
```

Now i get the following as expected:

```
   $('.selectpicker option:selected').text(); //outputs 'Mustard   Ketchup
```

But when i try to split the string, this doesn't work

```
  var text = $('.selectpicker option:selected').text(); //outputs 'Mustard   Ketchup
  var splitstr = text.split('    '); //does not split by 4 spaces only has an array of 1
```

Neither does this:

```
  var splitstr = text.split('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'); //does not split by 4 spaces only has an array of 1
   //kinda figured this wouldnt work,but took a shot anyway
```

I chose 4 spaces because my data has commas in it, so a comma delimiter won't work. How do i split a string by 4 spaces (    ) in javascript or jquery?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do i split a string by 4 spaces (    ) in javascript or jquery?

Use regular expressions to split:

```
var splitstr = text.split(/\s{4}/);
```

Comment: @BoundForGlory Great :)

Answer (score 3):

A non-breaking space isn't a space that we type. It's `String.fromCharCode(160)`. You'll want to spit it with four of those. If you were doing `$('.selectpicker option:selected').html()` (which is alright since `<option>` elements are fairly limited to what elements they can contain), then you could use four `&nbsp;` strings as a delimiter.

Here's what I recommend doing though:

```
var text = $('.selectpicker option:selected').text();
var nbsp = String.fromCharCode(160);
var splitstr = text.split(nbsp + nbsp + nbsp + nbsp);
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of splitting the string why not try extracting the separate strings into an array by iterating over $('.selectpicker option:selected') like this:

```
var arr = [];
$('.selectpicker option:selected').each(function() {
    arr.push( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Comment: I love this approach. Even though i'm glad i learned about splitting strings by spaces with regex

Comment: Yes regex is a skill sure worth learning – but all those nbsp’s in the source code would annoy the hell out of me.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this without going through the trouble of adding space delimiters to your `<option>` values by looping through each selected option and adding the value to an array.

```
var selected = [];
$('.selectedpicker option:selected').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).text());
}
```

[Edit]

[Toby T beat me to it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354851/splitting-a-string-by-nbsp-javascript-jquery/30355145#30355145)